# How can I get more than 11 characters into the name of my app on iPhone?

Tags: ios

The name I want to use for my app has 12 characters, I had read that Apple will only allow 11 at this time, but then I found an app with 13 (tiltshiftfocus). I was wondering if there is anything special I need to do in order to submit my 12 character app name?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243796/apple-ios-app-icon-title-maximum-length), it depends on the particular characters that are used.

For example, `w` takes up more space than `l`. `tiltshiftfocus` has lots of vertical line letters, which is probably why it fits.