# Apple iOS App icon title: maximum length?

Tags: ios

I was just wondering if there's a limit (in characters) for the iOS Apple app icon title (i.e. display name).
I want to avoid those ugly dots in the middle (Ex."Long..pple Name").

Comment: Application name? Or icon file name? iOS or Mac?

Comment: title appearing under IOS app icons

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on the width of each character in the display name. Between 11 (for "wwwwwww…") and 15 (for "iiiii…").

Answer (score 9):

1. Identify a name you wish to use for your app or web clip
2. Open Safari on the iOS device
3. Go to any web page
4. Tap the "Share" button (box with arrow pointing up)
5. Tap "Add to Home Screen" in the lower row of actions
6. Enter the intended name (copy/paste from notes is my favorite approach)
7. tap "Add"
   you will be taken back to the SpringBoard (aka home screen) and you will see the name fits or gets ellipsed. If it gets eclipsed, `GoTo Step 1`. If no ellipses, `Return`

Answer (score 6):

Not only does this depend on the width of every character, but the device and iOS version also makes a difference. For instance:

the iPhone 4 till 5 will truncate names faster then an iPhone 5s with iOS 8 (while an iPhone 5s with iOS 7 will also truncate a long title). The iPhone 6 & 6 plus have a wider display but do show only 4 icons, which means more space for your title.

The best way to test this, is with the iOS Simulator.

So as an answer to your question: There is not a real limit as it depends on character length, device width and iOS version...