# Is there is any way to break the line of App Name in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to my App Name it don't show full name rather just show its first name.[image]

Hear in the picture Google Setting shows full name. Is there is any way to show the App Name like this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The screenshot with Google Settings app doesn't seem to be from iOS.

Comment: @thanh Yes it is just an example I want to give.

Comment: in iOS your app name can be 11 characters long, which you can set in `Info.plist` file using 'bundleDisplayName' key. If its more than 11 characters it will be truncated.

Comment: Applications name on iPhone can't be multiline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " The length of your app name is limited to no longer than 50
>   characters. Notice how your app name will appear on the App Store for
>   each device, including each version of iPhone, iPad, and Apple TV. We
>   recommend keeping your app name to around 23 characters or less for
>   optimal presentation on every device. Long names may be truncated,
>   which means users will not see all the characters."
>   By Apple

- but I have read about this also. the safest number of character count
  is `11`. but it depends on few things such as the width of the
  characters your app name contains. the best way is to try it with
  your simulator and check.

for more refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243796/apple-ios-app-icon-title-maximum-length) and this link [App name by apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/)

**Addition : to change your app name for existing project**
go to `info.plist` and change the `bundle display name` , this is the name which display as `app name`